# Parameters for Jump to Report in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I have a report in Visual Studio 2010 with two fields that have jump to's.  Both jump to the same report.  However, one of them only requires 3 parameters to be passed whereas the other field requires 4.  How can I keep the same report that is being jumped to for both fields?  I can't figure out a way to not have to pass the Date parameter.  I know I can create a separate dataset and a separate report, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

```
SELECT        SalesData.SBLOC, SalesData.SBCUST, SalesData.RMNAME, SalesData.SBITEM, SalesData.IFPRVN, SalesData.SBITD1, SalesData.SBDIV, SalesData.SBCLS, 
                         SalesData.SBQSHP, SalesData.AVC, SalesData.SBEPRC, SalesData.SBINV, SalesData.SBORD, SalesData.SBTYPE, SalesData.SBINDT, SalesData.RMSTAT
FROM            SalesData INNER JOIN
                         FiscalCalendar ON SalesData.SBINDT = FiscalCalendar.FiscalDate
WHERE        (FiscalCalendar.FiscalYear = '2013') AND (SalesData.SBLOC IN (@Location)) AND (SalesData.SBTYPE = 'O') AND (FiscalCalendar.FiscalMonthName IN (@FiscalMonthName)) AND (FiscalCalendar.FiscalWeekNum IN (@FiscalWeekNum)) AND (FiscalCalendar.FiscalDate IN (@FiscalDate))
```

Comment: Depending on the differences between the 3-parameter and 4-parameter code, you may be able to default the 4th parameter... You should post some code, also, so it's easier to see where your problem is.

Comment: I added my SQL.  The issue is that I can only use one dataset and I don't know how to just default the date.